# MongoDB updating object in array not working (nodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am attempting to update a value within an array of objects when receiving a specific post from a user. However, it seems to only update when the matching value is the first element in the array. If the matching object is the first element in the array, it updates as expected. If it is not the first element, it is not updated. Replacing this with `findOne()` returns the object as expected. Am I missing something with how the `$` operator works?

```js
const response = await client
  .db("auth")
  .collection("users")
  .findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: new ObjectID(req.body.userId),
      "assignments.type": req.body.type,
      "assignments.number": req.body.number
      "assignments.complete": false
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "assignments.$.complete": true,
        "assignments.$.id": result.insertedId, // Previous call, is populated as expected
      }
    },
    {
      returnDocument: "after",
    }
  );
```

The document returned has the relevant value as `false` as is `response.value`.

Comment: `"assignments.$.id": result.insertedId`. What is the value of `result.insertedId` and what is the type of `assignments.$.id`? A bit weird that you are trying to update the id which supposes to be unique.

Comment: Can we see a sample document?